# Invalid Email Address Alert Using Bootstrap Alerts

Tags: javascript, alert

My goal is to alert users if they've entered an invalid email address using bootstrap's alert box.

I'm able to get the alert to pop up, however it only pop ups ONCE and won't alert after users close the alert box.

I got this far by adding the "collapse" class to the alert box to hide it initially, then added the "fade in" class if the condition is false.

Here's my code:

HTML:

```
    <div class="col-xs-12">
            <h4>To:</h4>
            <input type="text" name="email" id="email"> 
    </div>
    <div id="invalidEmail" class="col-xs-12 alert alert-warning alert-dismissible collapse" role="alert"> 
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span></button> 
        <strong>Invalid Email</strong>
    </div>
```

Javascript:

```
/*** Validate Email ***/


function validateEmail(){    
    var validate_email = $('input[name=email]').val();

    if( /(.+)@(.+){2,}\.(.+){2,}/.test(validate_email) ){
      emailPDF();
    } else {
      showAlert();
    }
}

/*** Show Invalid Email Alert Box ***/

function showAlert(){
    var alertBox = document.getElementById("invalidEmail");
    alertBox.className += " fade in";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now that I see that the bootstrap close is removing the invalidEmail div from the DOM, it makes more sense to me that you would add that from javascript. If you use this method, **there is no need to add and remove classes** because instead we are just adding and removing from the DOM. Also, if you add more fields and have to validate them as well, you can more easily re-purpose this to add similar HTML to other fields. Here is a working fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/n8ztvv61/3/

HTML

```
    <div id="myForm" class="col-xs-12">
      <h4>To:</h4>
      <input type="text" name="email" id="email"> 
      <button id="submit">
      button</button>
    </div>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
    // setup
$("#submit").on("click", validateEmail);

// adds html when the notice is needed
function showInvalidNotice() {
    $("#myForm").append('<div id="invalidEmail" class="col-xs-12 alert alert-warning alert-dismissible " role="alert"> <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span></button>       <strong>Invalid Email</strong></div>');
}

// validation
function validateEmail(){    
    var validate_email = $('input[name=email]').val();
    console.log("fired");
    if( /(.+)@(.+){2,}\.(.+){2,}/.test(validate_email) ){
      emailPDF();
    } else {
        showInvalidNotice();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. 

Do you have actual script examples on how I do this? I'm very new with javascript so any examples would be appreciated.

Comment: added script examples